# Need for Dynamic Screen Size

Tags: javascript, php

I have a need to be able to read the screen size during the execution of a php script.  Since that it is a client side issue I created a small script that executes javascript to obtain the screen size.  I call this script from my php program with curl.  It work great .. almost.  The value that is returned is correct but it is not in the form that can be used by php.  I tried it by setting a cookie but the cookie value return is always the value from the previous call.

if you want to see it run go here: 3wings.com/testScreenSize.php

Thanks for your help.

testScreenSize.php Code:

```
<?php
define(HTTPS_SERVER,'http://3wings.com');
$br='<br>';
$url = HTTPS_SERVER. '/getScreenSize.html';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 600);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($ret);echo $br;
echo ' $ret '.$ret.$br;
$scrwidth = $ret*1;
echo ' scrwidth '.$scrwidth.$br;
$cookieval = $_COOKIE['scrwidth'];
echo ' $cookieval '.$cookieval.$br;
```

getScreenSize.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<script>
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    document.cookie = "scrwidth=" + width + "; path=/";
    document.writeln(width);</script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am thoroughly puzzled. How can this work? there are no windows and widths on the server (where curl is executed)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - `getScreenSize.html` is being called using CURL; which is writing a cookie, which is attempting to be read server-side by the PHP, the theory is not a million miles off.

Comment: @CD001: yes, but the cookie is the backup solution. And I see `document.writeln` which, allegedly, produces correct but somehow unusable result

Comment: The problem, basically, is that you'd need to use a (JS capable) headless browser rather than CURL to run the JS to generate the output.

Comment: @CD001 and even with the cookie, there's no window. And no javascript execution. Which means, the cookie is only set __accidentally__, when Don echoes `$ret` (if I'm reading this right)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - heh, guess you were writing your comment as I was writing mine ;)

Comment: @CD001: "you'd need to use a headless browser" - presumably, OP wants to know the size of an actual user's browser window. In which case, just have a piece of JS write that cookie on every page load. And grab it when needed.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ... *OP wants to know the size of an actual user's browser* ... good point, well made - too busy looking at the technical side so I overlooked the obvious :D

Comment: @CD001  Thanks for the input. To clarify the curl appears to return the correct value but the $ret is actually 218 characters long. Looking at the source $ret value is the code from getScreenSize.html in quotes. I don't understand where the value displayed by echo $ret is coming from.